# The instance of entity type 'xxxx' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked Dapper Xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dapper

Using asp.net core 7 with NSubstitte, xunit, and Dapper, I have the below code as below

**Controller**

```
public async Task UpdateStatus(AuthorityStatusUpdateInputDto input)
        {
            int tenantId = AbpSession.GetTenantId();
            using var connection = _dapperContextBuilder.CreateConnection();
            var query = _dapperContextBuilder.QueryBuilder(new {Id = input.Id, TenantId = tenantId},
                "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Authority");
            Authority authority = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Authority>(query.Item1, query.Item2);

            authority.Status = input.Status;
            await _authorityRepository.UpdateAsync(authority);
        }
```

An interface with DapperContextBuilder

public interface IDapperContextBuilder

```
{
    IDbConnection  CreateConnection();
    (string, DynamicParameters) QueryBuilder(object conditions,  string query);
}
```

I am mocking the IDbConnection as below, since I am using Dapper with this library https://github.com/jmg48/NSubstitute.DbConnection to mock
the sql query and in-memory database as SQL-Lite

**Test**

```
private readonly IDbConnection _fakedbConnection;
 public AppService_Tests()
        {
            _fakedbConnection = Substitute.For<IDbConnection>().SetupCommands();
        }

         [Fact]
        public async Task Should_UpdateStatus_As_Edit()
        {
            // Arrange
            int id = 1001;
            _tenantId = AbpSession.TenantId ?? 0;
            _userId = AbpSession.UserId ?? 0;
            string query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Authority WHERE Id = @Id AND TenantId = @TenantId AND IsDeleted = 0";
            var connectionFactory = Substitute.For<IDapperContextBuilder>();
             connectionFactory.CreateConnection().Returns(_fakedbConnection);
            UsingDbContext(async context =>
            {
                CreateAuthorities(context, _tenantId, _userId);
                // Simulate Dapper behavior
                var item = context.Authority.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);
                _fakedbConnection.SetupQuery(query).Returns(item);
            });

            var dto = new AuthorityStatusUpdateInputDto()
            {
                Id = id,
                Status = AuthorityStatus.Edit
            };
            await _authorityAppService.UpdateStatus(dto);

            //Asserts
        }
```

The value is returned from the context as `var item = context.Authority.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id)`; however the exception is thrown as below and it is only
for Unit Test for the WEB API it is working fine.

**Exception**

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'Authority' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Attach(TEntity entity)
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.AttachIfNot(TEntity entity)
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.Update(TEntity entity)
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
   at LegalRegTech.MasterData.AuthorityAppService.SetAsDraft(Authority authority, AuthorityStatusUpdateInputDto input) in c:\6clicks\src\LegalRegTech.Application\MasterData\AuthorityAppService.cs:line 967
   at LegalRegTech.MasterData.AuthorityAppService.UpdateStatus(AuthorityStatusUpdateInputDto input) in c:\6clicks\src\LegalRegTech.Application\MasterData\AuthorityAppService.cs:line 639
   at LegalRegTech.Tests.Authority.AuthorityAppService_Tests.Should_UpdateStatus_As_Edit() in c:\6clicks\test\LegalRegTech.Tests\Authority\AuthorityAppService_Tests.cs:line 1042
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Comment: Your question title is misleading because you said ``....tracked by dapper`` which is not true, it's about EF tracking, however you can fix it by this: ``context.Authority.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);``

Comment: @sa-es-ir Yes it is been tracked by ef not dapper. I already tried context.Authority.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id); but didn't helped me

Comment: How about using this: ``context.ChangeTracker.Clear();`` before getting authority. but I wonder in the error it points to ``EfCoreRepositoryBase`` ??

Comment: are there any other tests in the class running in parallel, that also get an instance for Authority 1001 / does it work when you run this test alone?

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer I just run it single and it is not working, there were no test cased running in parallel.